# html: overlapping picture over sticky navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I need smbds help... 
I have a sticky navbar and recently added a div with some pictures (width:100%) and wanted to add some text in image, but when I am doing this, all goes over my sticky navbar (when scrolling down) which is below (hidden) this div (with pictures), but I want to have it always on top(my navbar)... ( I know there is a problem with position, but tried many things...).

CSS (div with img)

```
.container {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;}
```

CSS (DIV with my text in image)

```
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}
```

Answer (score 4):

Set `z-index` for your sticky element.

If your absolutely positioned elements have no explicit `z-index` you can set `z-index = 1;`, e.g.:

```
.sticky-element {
   position: sticky;
   top: 10; // or whatever you have
   z-index: 1;
}
```

However, I'm not aware why the browser behaves like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .sticky-navbar {
 position: sticky ;
 top : 0 ;
 z-index: 9 ;
 }

/*apply the above style to the class you're applying the position sticky to. */
```

Comment: this worked for me, i had same issue.

Comment: How is this meaningfully different from the accepted answer?